# Estimating probability of an occurrence from historical data

Tags: prediction-interval

I have 183 percentages based on the accuracy of a price prediction.  (If I predict something will sell at 100, and it sells at 100, then I have sold at 100% of the prediction.)  16 times, the percentage was < 85%.  I would like to know how to determine the probability of 100% of the percentages from another similar population would be < 85%.  In other words, what is the likelihood that the next group of assets I buy (chosen from the same population) would ALL be under 85% actual price / target price?

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is:

$$
\bigg(\frac{16}{183}\bigg)^n ,
$$

where $n$ is size of new group.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/181498)

Comment: I'm unsure why this is not an acceptable answer? The question is "what is the likelihood that the next group of assets I buy would ALL be under 85% actual price / target price?" Happy to delete if I misunderstood something...

Comment: I think he means 85% of the predicted value, not 85% probability. For an answer we would needv to know the distribution of prices, but we dont. So if you now agree in this, you could delete.

Comment: It's a confusingly worded question, but after a second read I stand by my answer: 16 of the 183 samples fell below the 85% threshold. Assuming future groups are taken from the same population, each item has a 16/183 chance of being <85%. so then just needs to be raised to the power of the size of the new group.